# Stripe is not declared

Tags: javascript, typescript, stripe-payments

I'm trying to import stripe:

```
import Stripe from "stripe"
```

It should work but I'm getting this error:

> `Could not find a declaration file for module 'stripe'. 'server/node_modules/stripe/lib/stripe.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

I tried to install `@types/stripe` but it didn't help and they are deprecated:

> `This is a stub types definition. stripe provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.`

This is the `package.json` file:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "license": "ISC",
    "scripts": {},
    "dependencies": {
        "stripe": "^11.8.0",
        "typescript": "^4.9.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        ...
    }
}
```

I don't have `type: "module"` and `@types/stripe`.

This is the `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "web/node_modules",
  ]
}
```

If I download stripe version `^10.17.0` everything works, so the problem is probably in stripe version `^11.8.0`.

Comment: The stripe package has built-in Typescript support. You do not need a separate library for types.

Comment: @BernardBorg, yes, but it still doesn't work. I have `@types/stripe` uninstalled and `stripe` installed. The error is the same

Comment: can you share your exact package.json file (and any other necessary information) for us to replicate it?

Comment: @alex. Just edited, please let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 0):

Node js doesn’t support ES6 import directly. You need to add `"type":"module"` in your `package.json` file to enables ES6 module support.